# Using Automapper with F# Entity Type Provider

Tags: entity-framework, f#, automapper, f#-data

I am looking at Automapper for the first time using F# and the Entity Type Provider.  I want to map between the EF Type Provider types and the F# record types that I have created.

The EF Type Provider is based on the following database schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Address](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FamilyId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [State] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [County] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [City] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Address] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Child](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FamilyId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Gender] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Grade] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Child] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Family](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [IsRegistered] [bit] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Family] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Parent](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FamilyId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Parent] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Pet](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ChildId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GivenName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Pet] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Address]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Address_Family] FOREIGN KEY([FamilyId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Family] ([Id])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Address] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Address_Family]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Child]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Child_Family] FOREIGN KEY([FamilyId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Family] ([Id])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Child] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Child_Family]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Parent]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Parent_Family] FOREIGN KEY([FamilyId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Family] ([Id])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Parent] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Parent_Family]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Pet]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Pet_Child] FOREIGN KEY([ChildId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Child] ([Id])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Pet] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Pet_Child]
```

I then created a comparable set of types in F#:

```
type Pet = {Id:int; GivenName:string}
type Child = {Id:int; FirstName:string; Gender:string; Grade:int; Pets: Pet list}
type Address = {Id:int; State:string; County:string; City:string}
type Parent = {Id:int; FirstName:string}
type Family = {Id:int; Parents:Parent list; Children: Child list; Address:Address}
```

The only real difference is that the foreign key is not explicit in the record types.

When I use Automapper on the Address type, it works as expected:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<EntityConnection.ServiceTypes.Address, Address>()
let context  = EntityConnection.GetDataContext()
let addressQuery = query {for address in context.Addresses do select address}
let address = Seq.head addressQuery
let address' = Mapper.Map<Address>(address)

val address' : Address = {Id = 1;
                          State = "WA";
                          County = "King";
                          City = "Seattle";}
```

But when I try and do the same with the entire graph,

```
Mapper.CreateMap<EntityConnection.ServiceTypes.Pet, Pet>()
Mapper.CreateMap<EntityConnection.ServiceTypes.Child, Child>()
Mapper.CreateMap<EntityConnection.ServiceTypes.Address, Address>()
Mapper.CreateMap<EntityConnection.ServiceTypes.Parent, Parent>()
Mapper.CreateMap<EntityConnection.ServiceTypes.Family, Family>()

let context  = EntityConnection.GetDataContext()
let familyQuery = query {for family in context.Families do select family}
let family = Seq.head familyQuery

let family' = Mapper.Map<Family>(family)
```

I get this exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Type needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args
Parameter name: type
```

I am wondering if it is b/c EF is lazy loading so the remaining types are not being evaluated?  has anyone seen this before?

Comment: May I recommend dumping AutoMapper from your toolbox if you care about sensible types in your programs.

Comment: bit old, but what happens if you don't use FSharp list and use array in you record definitions. Things might start working as array is a non F# specific type.

Comment: @GregC The alternative is writing the code. It's better because the compiler can check things and you can reason about your code. Another alternative would be compile-time macros but that's not very well supported in .NET yet.

Comment: @GregC https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/5674940-implement-syntactic-macros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty straight forward.  None of your classes have a constructor that takes 0 arguments.

F# creates default constructors for you so the default constructor on your class has multiple arguments in it. For example:

```
type Pet = {Id:int; GivenName:string}
```

as a c# class would have this as it's definition.

```
public class Pet
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string GivenName { get; private set; }
    public Pet(int id, string givenName)
    {
        Id = id;
        GivenName = givenName;
    }
}
```

Note the lack of a parameterless constructor.  That's where your error is coming from.

You can fix it by flagging your type as CLIMutable

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type Pet = {Id:int; GivenName:string}
```

Comment: That got me from 1 error to the next: AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.  Mapping types:
EntityCollection`1 -> FSharpList`1